# responsive image with maphilight.js

Tags: image, github, dictionary, imagemap, imagemapster

My images stop being responsive after I enable maphilight.

First I made the imagemaps responsive with rwdImageMaps.js, works fine. But after I enable maphilight the images themselves stop being responsive. (The imagemaps stay responsive though.)

From chrome inspect: [without maphilight](http://content.screencast.com/users/ludop/folders/Jing/media/63cf1ae6-ebda-4928-b166-e4e2cb2b101f/2014-11-23_1227.png), [With maphilight](http://content.screencast.com/users/ludop/folders/Jing/media/f232bd7c-d3f5-4e92-ac62-3f810cd8b7cf/2014-11-23_1228.png).

You can see that maphilight.js changes the image with from 100%, responsive to a div with a fixed with and height.
How can I make the image / div responsive again?
(I also tried ImageMapster but that resulted in the same issue.)

Can somebody help me solve this? Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: The scaling is working fine now, exept the maphilights.
Using the jQuery-maphilight.js from andensolutions not even the default behavior shows. Even though I put a data-maphilight in the area with a fillcolor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this link. [Responsive image maps with roll-overs](http://www.andensolutions.com/blog/responsiveImagePaths#comment-13029)

Please also note that you might need to reduce the opacity of your image if it's not transparent, for the solution to work properly

Comment: Sweet it works! Thanks
But what would be the best order of the scripts, map_rollover.js as last since that uses both img[usemap]maphilight and rwdImageMaps. Or their written div_offset script block ?

Comment: First rwdImageMaps.js, second maphilight.js and finally map_rollover.js would be the correct order

Comment: @EtienneMartin I checked http://emartin.ca/mapify/ as it is said that it is responsive but I checked this in iphone 6 plus, the image map is not shrinking to fit to the window

Comment: @sukhjinder-singh This is to demonstrate the scrolling effect with the popovers. Simply remove the min-width from the css to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the library jquerymobile 2.1.1 ?
I had the same problem and this worked for me